# How to fix "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object"

Tags: node.js, express

I am having an error with an express routing app

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({ msg: 'Users Works' }));

module.exports = router;
```

> TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Objec

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if there is no // module.exports = router; //

If it error still continues, then you might have a middleware that is not yet set up that executes before this route.

Answer (score 0):

Export Router From First File like this.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Post.find();
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Some Data",
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Then Import in other root files like this and use

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const todo = require("./routes/todo/todo");
app.use("/todo", todo);
```

> For Reference [Complete Nodejs Routing App](https://github.com/hamsahmedansari/Todo-App-Server)